# How do I center a box and its contents in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have had look at some of the other answers but could not get them working for my particular case.  I have simplified and included the entire block of code below.  Basically it just displays text in a blue box.  I would like to know how to center the box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
#content {
width:500px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: #D1ECFF;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
--></style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">

    <h2>Create</h2>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are the styles for the h2? Where are the styles that define a "blue box"? In order to answer your question we need to know if each element has a **fixed** or **variable** height and width. Without these details your question is *extremely* vague, and will not only be difficult to answer but will also be much less helpful to others with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because `#content` has a width, you can set the left and right margins to `auto`. This will center the element in its parent. The short bit of code `margin: 0 auto;` sets top/bottom margin to zero and left/right to auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/vL5r2/

```
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:500px; 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the box *and* its contents both vertically an horizontally you could do it with absolute positioning and negative margins as can be seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNY4L/1/).